# Anime where the school boy hero is good with puzzles, can fly with an item he collects

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching a anime in which the hero school boy is good with puzzles,and they collect some lockets, or something, he can fly when he attaches one thing he collected, they collect with different levels of attack,defense specs.

Comment: Are you possibly thinking of Yugioh? The main character Yugi is good with puzzles, and the various monsters in the card game Duel Monsters have different levels of attack and defence,

Comment: sound like greed island arc in `hunter x hunter`.

Comment: Hi, this question would be improved by looking at [how to ask a good story id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and include things like original language, style of anime, year it was watched (to help pin down a range for when it was released) etc. Please do [edit] that information in when you're able to

Answer (score 0):

[*Phi Brain: Puzzle of God*](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/phi-brain-puzzle-of-god) is a decent superficial match for "good with puzzles," but I'm not certain that he can fly.

> No one loves puzzles more than Kaito Diamon, and when it comes to solving them, he's the best there is. But when a labyrinth underneath his school leads him to an mysterious armband that can unlock his brain's full potential, he is put on the Puzzle Of God organization's radar as one of the children of Phi-Brain. Now he must push his mind to the limit as the P.O.G. challenges him relentlessly to their deadly puzzles. With a plethora of dangerous, laughable, creative, or down-right demented puzzles being thrown at him, will Kaito have what it takes to solve his way to victory or will he fall against the puzzles he adores so much?

### Trailer

Comment: thanks for the response dude, but i don't think this is the one on my mind..